# Move lines horizontally when removing from left end of chart

Tags: javascript, animation, charts, chart.js

In Chart.JS when doing this to a chart:

```
config.data.labels.shift(); // remove the label first

config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, datasetIndex) {
   dataset.data.shift();
});

window.myLine.update();
```

The lines of the chart fly all around the place instead of moving to the left. Ive uploaded this example here: [Example](http://venion.net/chartjs/line.html)

Click "Remove Data" to see how chart.js draws the removal of datapoints at the left end of the chart. It looks as if its generating new points, but the datapoints actually "move left" to where there where the old points before, the animation just makes it look so weird.

In v1 of Chart.js there was a function removeData() where this happened correctly, with all the datapoints and lines scrolling horizontally to the left instead of moving crazy.

Since I want to create a chart where theres new data coming in from the right and should be removed at the left, I seek to accomplish this somehow.